# Increase MySQL queries per second

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

I have a PHP script (HTTP API Web service) which does `INSERT` and `SELECT` data from a MySQL database. It has 3 `SELECT` queries and 2 `INSERT`  queries.

This P>HP script is called 10,000 times per second by other servers by HTTP GET to an URL like http://myserver.com/ws/script.php?colum1=XXX&column2=XXX

However, only 200 records are stored per second.

I use an Intel(R) Core(TM) Quad Core i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 32 GB RAM, Cent 0S with cpanel, 2TB SATA HDD.

How can I increase the amount of queries per second?

Comment: You need to edit the question to provide more information on the queries and data structures.  In all likelihood, the solution is to get better hardware.

Comment: and maybe another database (noSQL), that is designed for huge amounts of data and very quick inserts/selects

Comment: @Jeff i do agree with you , for mysql server 10,000 requests per second may result to no database connection error , you better use some kind of document based database like : mongodb which is way faster then mysql.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/118504/how-to-improve-mysql-insert-and-update-performance

Comment: A note on NoSQL: if your reads are simple and don't require joins, NoSQL is likely your best bet, since writes are always fast and flat reads that read data straight from a collection without joins are nearly equally as fast as writes.  As soon as joins come into play, performance degrades.

Comment: I'd like to chime in and say, that SSD disk will increase your throughput.

Comment: There is a practical limit to SATA as it is a sequential read/write device.  Your hardware is preventing speed.  In addition, if you are querying and then inserting into the same table sets, that will cause a pretty significant slowdown.  TPS is not a simple thing in most cases.  Largely it will come down to 1) what your system is - and SATA is not a good choice for this, 2) what the base architecture is (table structures, for example) and 3) what kinds of data are being stored (relational db are known to not like sequential data much - logs are best at the O/S).  More information is req'd.

Comment: Take a look at your iostat and vmstat on CentOS.  That will give you information.

Comment: Dear All, Thank you for your quick answer. My database is with single table. I save Some INTEGER columns ( ex-timestamp), some VARCHAR  columns and one TEXT column. I use INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT query. I am now planing to change the hardware to Intel® Xeon® E5-1650 v3
Hexa-Core Haswell 
incl. Hyper-Threading Technology
RAM256 GB DDR4 ECC RAMHard Drive2 x 4 TB SATA 6 Gb/s 7200 rpm
HDD (Software-RAID 1)
Class Enterprise

Comment: And also i am going to use the noSQL database. I searched in the google there are many no SQL database such us Oracle,  MangoDB. which is best? and Do i need to use  SSD disk instred of  SATA. then i can useHard Drive2 x 480 GB SATA 6 Gb/s
Data Center Series
SSD (Software-RAID 1)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options to increase database performance

- enable MySQL query caching if not already enabled (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html)
- add indexes on search columns
- optimize queries (e.g. by avoiding deep sub-selects or complex query-conditions or checking framework/orm for unnecessary join logic)
- changing engine (e.g. InnoDB to MyISAM)
- using a more scaleable dbms (e.g. MariaDB instead of MySQL)
- using one or more mirrors on additional hardware (slave databases for reading only) and using a load-balancer

Comment: I have already enabled MySQL query caching , added indexes , MyISAM engine